# How to transform vertical python dataframe into a horizontal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python that includes parent mapping, and is basically being used to map multiple levels of items in a hierarchy. My dataframe looks like this (this example has 3 levels, but there is no limit on how deep the data can go):

```
id,name,parent_id
1,fruits,0
2,vegetables,0
3,apple,1
4,potato,2
5,pear,1
6,red apple,3
7,green apple,3
```

I need to get the data in a new dataframe, that looks like this:

```
id,level_1,level_2,level_3
1,fruits,NaN,NaN
2,vegetables,NaN,NaN
3,fruits,apple,NaN
4,vegetables,potato,NaN
5,fruits,pear,NaN
6,fruits,apple,red apple
7,fruits,apple,green apple
```

I'm at a loss for how I would do this. I was thinking maybe merging the dataframes repeatedly on the parent ID column, but not sure that's the best way. Can anyone offer some advise for how to do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
name_parent = df.set_index(['id'])['parent_id'].to_dict()
id_name = df.set_index(['id'])['name'].to_dict()

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_new['level1'] = df['id']
df_new['level2'] = df_new['level1'].map(name_parent)
df_new['level3'] = df_new['level2'].map(name_parent)


df_new=df_new.replace({0:np.NaN})
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df_new.values,axis=1),columns=dfx.columns)
df_new = dfx.applymap(lambda x: id_name.get(x))
df_new['id'] = df['id']
df_new = df_new.applymap(lambda x: np.NaN if x ==None else x)
```

output:

```
    level1  level2  level3  id
0   fruits  NaN NaN 1
1   vegetables  NaN NaN 2
2   fruits  apple   NaN 3
3   vegetables  potato  NaN 4
4   fruits  pear    NaN 5
5   fruits  apple   red apple   6
6   fruits  apple   green apple 7
```